# How do i submit mutiple crispy forms in django using one submit button?

Tags: python, django

I have two separate forms which i am trying to render in a single template.
However when i am trying to submit the form, the form is not getting submitted.
Is there any possible way to do this? It is working fine when i am not using crispy forms

forms.py

```
class BasicInfoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BasicInfo
        fields = '__all__'

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class = 'form-group'
    helper.layout = Layout(
                        Row(
                            Column('name', css_class='form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4'),
                            ),
                        Row(
                            Column('birthMonth',css_class='form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4'),
                            ),
                        Row(
                            Column('birthYear', css_class='form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4'),
                            ),
                        )

class IncomeDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = IncomeDetail
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_class = 'form-group'
    helper.layout = Layout(
                        Row(
                            Column('gross', css_class='form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4'),
                            Column('monthlyExpense',css_class='form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4'),
                            Column('hasSavingsInvestment', css_class='form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4'),
                            ))
```

Views.py

```
def getIndexDetails(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
        print("inside post method")
        basicinfoform = BasicInfoForm(request.POST)
        if basicinfoform.is_valid():
            basicinfoform.save()
            incomedetailform= IncomeDetailForm(request.POST)
        if incomedetailform.is_valid():
            incomedetailform.save()



<form action="." method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ crispy basicinfoform }}
        {% crispy incomedetailform %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit Button">                 
      </form>
```

Comment: Is it your whole relevant code for the forms.py? Just wondering where's the ` __init__()` method to contain the helper() definitions.

Comment: i have not put any init method and field styling is  working without init, not sure if init method needs to be put

Answer (score 0):

If you check/inspect your HTML code in the browser, you'd see two `form` tags nested under an outer `form` tag (the one added by you).

You need to avoid this situation by adding

```
helper.form_tag = False
```

to helper objects under each forms.